# How do I give best2 this assignment as an array?

Tags: arrays

Assume  that two parallel arrays  have been declared  and initialized : healthOption an array  of type  char  that contains letter codes for different healthcare options and annualCost an array  of type  int . The i-th element  of annualCost indicates the annual cost of the i-th element  of healthOption. In addition, there is an char  variable , best2.Write the code necessary to assign  to best2 the health option with the lower annual cost, considering only the first two healthcare options.

Thus, if the values  of healthOption are 'B', 'Q', 'W', 'Z' and the values  of annualCost are 8430, 9400, 7050, 6400 your code would assign  'B' to best2 because 8430 is less than  9400 and is associated with 'B' in the parallel array . (We ignore 'W' and 'Z' because we are considering only the first two options.)

Answer (score 1):

```
  int[] annualCost = new int[] { 8430, 9400, 7050, 6400 }
  char[] healthOption = new char[] { 'B', 'Q', 'W', 'Z' };
  int[] annualCostbest2 = new int[] { annualCost[0],annualCost[1] };
```

//Get Minimum value from Your array

```
 int min = annualCostbest2.Min();
```

//Take index of lowest price value

```
   int index = Array.IndexOf(annualCostbest2, min);
```

//Get value from your 2nd array

```
 char  best2 = healthOption[index];
```

Comment: This didn't really solve my problem, I think it's a simpler answer I just don't know how to assign best2 the health option with the lower annual cost for the homework problem it also suggests I use < for some reason.

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly you want and what is the scenario... where you want to use the solution ?